# Get input value except the last by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want getting all value in inputs except the last input in last class `.tr` by jquery, but it don't work for me, How can fix it?

I try as:

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/d4xZK/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="tr">
    <input type="text" value="111">
</div>
<div class="tr">
    <input type="text" value="222">
</div>
<div class="tr">
    <input type="text" value="333">
</div>
<div class="tr">
    <input type="text" value="444">
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.tr').each(function(){
    var mpiVal = $('.tr input').not(':last').val();
    alert(mpiVal)
)}
```

Comment: there is a console error in your fiddle corrected http://jsfiddle.net/d4xZK/2/

Comment: @Devjosh Yes, there is a syntax mistake in last line..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [`slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) off the last one:

```
$('.tr').slice(0, -1).each(function() {
    var mpiVal = $('input', this).val();
    console.log(mpiVal);
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/e5T7X/)

Comment: @ jack please check in firebug console there should be }) instead of )} at the end

Comment: @Devjosh Nah, I forgot to fork the fiddle, so I used the OP's version, which was obviously wrong and didn't contain my code :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.tr').not(':last').each(function(){
    var mpiVal = $(this).children('input').val();
    alert(mpiVal)
});
```

Demo here http://jsfiddle.net/d4xZK/4/

Answer (score 1):

Or you can simply use the right selectors for that;

```
$('.tr:not(:last) input').each(function(){
    var mpiVal = $(this).val();
    alert(mpiVal);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax mistake in last line

```
  var arr = []
  $('.tr:not(:last)').each(function(){
     arr.push.call(arr,$(this).find('input').first().val());         
  });
  alert(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".tr:not(:last) input").map(function(){ return $(this).val() }).get()
```

Returns `["111", "222", "333"]`